# IPython kernel restarts after installing new module

Tags: python, ipython

I was using "ipython" with "qtconsole" (it works perfectly) after I install some new third-party module and the "notebook" it stops working and the kernel restarts continually.

the Error is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/kernel/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
raise ImportError(__doc__)
ImportError: IPython.kernel has been replaced by IPython.parallel.

The previous version of IPython's parallel library was located at this
location (IPython.kernel). It has been moved to the IPython.parallel
subpackage and has been refactored to use zeromq/pyzmq instead of twisted.

Please see INSERT URL for further details.

[IPythonQtConsoleApp] WARNING | kernel restarted
```

how can I fix this issue? 
the Error says "Please see INSERT URL for further details." where can I find this "INSERT URL" ???
thank you.

Comment: it would help to know at least what library you installed that caused the problem...

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple versions of IPython installed, and it's getting confused. The version in `/usr/lib` is installed with `apt`, and old (pre-1.0).

The shortest workaround, if available to you, would be to `apt-get remove ipython`, leaving only one IPython on your system.

The most likely *cause* of this issue, since you say it was caused by installing another package, is `easy_install`. It is possible for easy_install to incorrectly add dist-packages to easy-install.pth when you already have a package installed with apt.  To check this, look at the files (if they exist):

```
~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/easy-install.pth
```

If there are any entries starting with `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, they should be removed.